# ¿Cómo multiplicar y sumar inputs con miles y decimales, con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿De qué manera puedo multiplicar y a la vez sumar esos totales, donde mi `input` tiene como valor `value="2.500.000,00"`?.

Quiero multiplicar y sumar sin tener que quitar los puntos y decimales, ya que si se los quito mi código funciona perfectamente, pero quiero hacerlos con los puntos y decimales.

Estoy tomando el valor de los `input` por medio de los `tr`.

**Anexo Fragmento de mi código**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="input" value="2.500.000,00">  </td>
                <td>    <input type="number" class="input">                     </td>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="total"  disabled>             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="input" value="4.500.000,00" >  </td>
                <td>    <input type="number" class="input">                      </td>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="total"  disabled>              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TOTAL</td>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="totales" value="0" disabled>   </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
 
<script>
var input=document.querySelectorAll(".input");
input.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click",multiplica);
    e.addEventListener("keyup",multiplica);
});
function multiplica() {
    var tr=this.closest("tr");
    var total=1;
    var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll(".input");
    inputs.forEach(function(e) {
        total*=e.value;
    });
    tr.querySelector(".total").value=total.toFixed(2);
    calcularTotal(this.closest("table"));
}
function calcularTotal(e) {
    var total=0;
    var totales=e.querySelectorAll(".total");
    totales.forEach(function(e) {
        total+=parseFloat(e.value);
    });
    e.getElementsByClassName("totales")[0].value=total.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Los números se trabajan como eso... números. Si quieres agregarle los puntos y eso, se hace después de obtener el resultado.

Comment: Lo que dice Excorpion es lo que he intentado decirte en la otra pregunta

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente lo que me dicen. Pero entonces no existe una manera?. @JeanGotopo quise separar mi problema anterior para luego construir uno solo

Comment: Si existe una manera... trabaja el 2500000 como un 2500000... cuando ya hayas hecho los calculos, toma el resultado y dale el formato visual que quieras.

Comment: entonces la respuesta es que no existe una manera, por ahora no quiero darle formato gracias

Comment: LO QUE QUIERES ES DARLE UN FORMATO !!! literalmente, eso ES darle un formato.

Comment: No recuerdo que tipo de formato, pero se que los puntos como separadores de miles y comas en decimales, es uno de los tipos de formato.

Comment: Incluso me doy el tiempo de dejarte tipos de formato en JS para que eligas el que quieres usar. -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: Me explico, el formato puedo dárselo cuando obtenga el resultado, formatear el resultado se hacerlo. pero creí que existía una manera de multiplicar un valor como "2.500,00"

Comment: Si... la manera de hacerlo, es como te estamos diciendo. Un número no es un conjunto de caracteres, son números. Y dependiendo de que leguaje uses, los decimales se auto-separaran con punto o con coma. Por eso 2.500,00 DEBES trabajarlo como 2500... luego usas el formato que te convenga, ya sea el de USA, españa, o incluso uno personalizado.

Comment: para trabajar con números como lo indicas tiene primero que convertirlo de texto a numero en este caso `Float`, trabajar en el código con el `float` y el resultado entonces volver a formatearlo al formato que te agrede visualmente. los numero con separadores son evaluados como texto por eso debes convertirlos a flotante, incluso todo lo que tengas en un input será evaluado como texto y estas obligado a transfórmalo antes de usarlos en formulas, en este caso al tipo de numero correcto `parseFloat` para flotantes y `parseInt` para enteros.

Comment: esta respuesta es la mas acertada y completa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/460691/46896

Comment: Perfecto, eso era lo que buscaba formatear mi input a tipo float , ya que como comentas siempre sera evaluados como texto, ya sea que tenga separador de miles y decimales o no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al realizar los cálculos debes "limpiar" valores:

- Eliminar puntos con `.replaceAll('.', '')`
- Remplazar coma por punto con `.replace(',', '.')`

Después de eso, `2.500.000,00` pasará a ser una cadena que Javascript puede interpretar como número: `2500000.00`.

Ahora, si el valor de un campo no se puede interpretar como número, por ejemplo, si es una cadena vacía, `parseFloat()` devolverá `NaN` y solo necesitas agregar `|| 0` al final de la línea para asegurar que tienes un valor numérico.

Para más información, lee los comentarios en el código:

```js
let input = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
input.forEach(function(e) {
    // Solo es necesario un evento, no necesitas otros
    e.addEventListener("input", multiplica);
});
function multiplica() {
    let tr = this.closest("tr");

    // inputs[0] es precio, primera posición
    // inputs[1] es cantidad
    let inputs = tr.querySelectorAll(".input");
    
    // Eliminar puntos, remplazar coma por punto y asegurar que es un número
    // Si algo falla, el valor será cero
    let precio = parseFloat(inputs[0].value.replaceAll('.', '').replace(',', '.')) || 0;

     // El input de cantidad es numérico, no es necesario hacer remplazos
    let cantidad = parseFloat(inputs[1].value) || 0;
    
    // Calcuar total de esta fila
    tr.querySelector('.total').value = (precio * cantidad).toFixed(2);
    
    calcularTotal(this.closest("table"));
}
function calcularTotal(e) {
    let total = 0;
    let totales = e.querySelectorAll(".total");
    totales.forEach(function(input) {
        // Asegurar que es un valor numérico o cero
        total += parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
    });
    e.querySelector('.totales').value = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="input" value="2.500.000,00">  </td>
                <td>    <input type="number" class="input">                     </td>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="total" readonly>             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="input" value="4.500.000,00" >  </td>
                <td>    <input type="number" class="input">                      </td>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="total" readonly>              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TOTAL</td>
                <td>    <input type="text" class="totales" value="0" readonly>   </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Al final si quiere mantener la retro-compatibilidad con el sistema numérico que ha implementado debe de ejecutar:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(total)
```

Con esto el string de salida será `2.500.000,00`

**Recomendación:** Declara tus variables con `let` en vez de `var` para limitar el contexto y evitar colisiones o reescribir variables globales.

Comment: Tal y como se le ha dicho al OP, esta es la forma de trabajar los valores. Ahora, si quiere que visualmente se VEAN, con separadores de miles y decimales, DEBE aplicarle un formato a los inputs, para que obtenga el 100% de lo quiere.

Comment: @Excorpion ya edite la respuesta... el OP quiere mantener la compatibilidad con el sistema numérico.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Triby y también a Francisco Núñez eso era lo que quería mantener el formato de miles y decimales y luego quitárselo para poder trabajarlo como entero y así poder multiplicarlo sin que me de error de NaN, Gracias a Excorpion por comentar

Comment: Aún nadie agrega el formato a los inputs, pero bue... al menos el OP acepto una respuesta.

Comment: @Excorpion, lo que quería OP era poder mantener el formato en los _inputs_ y realizar operaciones sin obtener `NaN`.

Comment: Lo se, pero solo mantuvieron el formato en la columna precio, nadie le dio el formato al precio total, y estoy 100% seguro que el OP aun no diferencia valores de formatos, por eso nunca me respondió.

Comment: @Excorpion, en el primer comentario de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/460689/54039) OP menciona que sabe cómo dar formato y, de cualquier forma, la edición de Francisco en mi respuesta sugiere cómo lograrlo.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando calcules el total que tengas por ejemplo:

```
var total = 25000000
```

Entonces puedes usar un método de Javascript que es bien directo con le formato de miles:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat().format(total) //Esto te lo transformará en 25.000.000
```

Comment: La parte de dar formato la conozco bien, pero supongamos que este total tiene separador de miles y decimales como lo multiplicas?

Comment: @TheRiddler, tal y como ha puesto triby, verás que las multiplicaciones funcionan correctamente, solo que falta añadirle el formato que tu quieres, el cual usa . como separador de miles y , para decimal.

Comment: Lo que intentamos decirte Excorpion y yo es que ningún lenguaje te va dar como resultado un número ya formateado en miles y decimales, esto es, porque el formatos con puntos y comas depende de la región, y también por lo tipado de los lenguajes: el tipo de variable. Todo número por muy grande que sea, el lenguaje de programación lo devuelve sin formato. Como te dice @Excorpion tu puedes mostrarlo luego de haber tratado ese número con, por ejemplo, el método que te he puesto en la respuesta. Ya pasado por el método lo colocas donde quieras que se vea así.